# Each of the two sets is recursively enumerable given their cartesian product is

Tags: computability, enumeration

$A \times B$ is an r.e. set,  I want to show that $A$ (or $B$) is  r.e.

Comment: Then you also need that $B$ (or $A$) is non-empty.

Comment: @HendrikJan: Right, I forgot to mention that condition. Thanks.

Comment: As $A\times B$ is in RE, this means there is an algorithm that generates (in any order) the pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. For $A$ you need to generate a sequence of $a\in A$ (in any order, repetitions allowed).

Comment: @HendrikJan: That I knew, but I need to find a formula. I've got an idea that I should use the symbolic definition of an r.e. set. That is, writing a formula for the function that specifies $A$ or $B$, assuming a formula exists for $A \times B$.

Comment: @HendrikJan If $A$ or $B$ is empty then $A$ or $B$ is r.e.

Comment: Gigili, What do you mean "formula"?  If your task is to show what the post asks, then surely @HendrikJan answers the question.

Comment: @PålGD: What Hendrik said is somehow the definition of Cartesian product and is pretty straight forward. I'm more interested in solutions that don't use that definition.

Comment: @PålGD The point is that when $A$ is empty (and RE), then $A\times B$ is empty (and RE) while $B$ might *not* be RE. So the implication (for $B$) is not valid.

Comment: @Gigili Yes it is the definition. I wanted to point out that $A$ is just the first component ("projection") of $A\times B$ (assuming $B$ is not empty). That more-or-less is the solution to your question. Of course there are different formalisms for RE, and you have to tune the construction to the definition you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you want: with the same idea as @HendrikJan and with a function:

$A\times B$ is r.e. hence, there is a partial recursive function $f$ such that: 
$$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0 &\mbox{if}\ x \in A\times B \\ \mbox{undefined/does not halt}\ &\mbox{if}\ x \notin A\times B \end{matrix}\right. $$

$A$ is not empty let $a$ be an element of $A$ ($a\in A$).

Let $g$ be the partial recursive function defined as $g(x)=f(a,x)$.

$g(x)=0$ iff $f(a,x)=0$ iff $(a,x)\in A\times B$ iff $x\in B$. Hence $B$ is r.e.

Answer (score 1):

We assume both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty.

If $A\times B$ is r.e., then it is definable by a $\Sigma^{0}_{1}$ formula: 
$$
(a,b) \in A\times B \Longleftrightarrow \exists x \, R(a,b,x), 
$$
where $R$ is a recursive predicate. Thus 
$$
a\in A \Longleftrightarrow \exists x \, \exists \, b R(a,b,x),
$$
so $A$ is definable by a $\Sigma^{0}_{1}$ formula and hence r.e. Similarly for $B$.